# Thunderbird moves email marked as "not junk" back into junk folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I am using various versions of Thunderbird on systems running 16.04.02 and 17.04MATE.

Each of these systems has a quirk that I cannot figure out.

When an email which has been identified as junk is marked as "not junk", it should be untagged and moved to the inbox. FULL STOP.

However, in every version 48.x and 52.x, Thunderbird reprocesses the mail and RE-marks it as junk and, moves it BACK into the junk folder for that account. Additionally, it creates another copy of the message such that there are now TWO messages marked as junk.

I have reset to defaults, I have adjusted global junk settings, and I have even tried to reset junk mail handling. The behaviour continues and is making Thunderbird basically unusable since I have many crypto accounts that are being ID'd as junk mail.

Looking for options which will normalize junk mail handling in Thunderbird.

Thanks

Comment: I deal with junk mail long before my email client picks it up so YMMV.  If you click on enable adaptive junk mail controls for each account in question, TB should learn from each junk / not junk button push.  If you enable preferences->security->adaptive junk filter logging you can push the "show log" button now and then to see how TB is doing.  Mail from senders that are in your personal address list should never be flagged as junk.

Comment: Do you have any `message filters` set up? Example... if subject contains XYZ then copy message to mailbox ABC and mark as junk.

Comment: @heynnema - No message filters. I barely changed any defaults on the installation. I did enable adaptive junk mail filters. Turning this off has no positive effect. it's as if it doesn't really do anything. All I did on each install was to let Tbird setup my email accounts with its automatic setup. I just entered the email address and password... Tb did the rest. But, three installs all have the same issue. --- jones0610 - I wish it worked that way. But, for some reason, it doesn't. There must be something in common with these three machines... I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Does the Tools/Activity Manager give you any clues? Do you have any Thunderbird extensions installed?

Comment: So sorry. I thought I responded to your question. The activity manager doesn't show anything that I can recognize as a problem. All looks pretty routine to me. There are no extensions installed other than the new calendar thingy that is now installed by default.